# Why is the infinitive verb used?

Tags: grammar

Why is the infinitive verb 'break' used in the following sentence:

He called the police after having spotted a burglar break into his neighbour's house.

Comment: Probably the writer was thinking in analogy to the usage with auxiliary verbs: “A burglar **would break** into any such house.” Would you expect a present participle instead: “He spotted a burglar **breaking** in”?

Comment: [Hear, see, etc. + object + infinitive or -ing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing)

Answer (score 3):

> *He called the police after having spotted a burglar* [*break into his*
> *neighbour's house*].

Your example is called a catenative construction; one where the catenative verb "spot" requires either an infinitival clause or a gerund-participial (-*ing*) clause as complement.

Semantically, the infinitival clause suggests that he spotted the whole break-in, while the gerund-participial clause suggests that "he" spotted only a segment of it.

Note that the intervening NP, "a burglar", is the syntactic object of "spotted" and the *understood* subject of the subordinate clause.